# How to generate dynamic external link?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm new in php and css.
My goal is to put two icons into main menù of a wordpress site. these icons should point to dynamic external links to my domain.
My header.php code of my theme is:

```
<div id="flags" style="position:absolute;left:97%;top:10px; width:300px; height:30px; background-color:transparent">
    <a href="mydomain.com/aaa/"><img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/it-icon-24.png" /></a>
    <a href="mydomain.com/bbb/"><img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/uk-icon-24.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I need to take the current URL, replace only a part of that with a string of my choice. For example, into the first url, the string "aaa" with "ccc".
Thus, the icon link to the new address.

I tried to follow this way:

```
<div id="flags" style="position:absolute;left:97%;top:10px; width:300px; height:30px; background-color:transparent">
    <?php
        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $strEng = "eng";
        $strIta = "ita";
        $new_link = str_replace($strEng,$strIta, $actual_link);
    ?>
    <div id="banner" onclick="window.location.href='$new_link'" style="cursor: pointer">
        <img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/it-icon-24.png" />
    </div>
    <a href="mydomain.com/bbb/"><img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/uk-icon-24.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Can you give me advice on how to write the correct code and in which files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make a translatable site.
What I think you should do is use the large plugin community from WordPress to make your site translatable. (WPML, WordPress MultiLingual is a great one)

If you do want to do it this way, or want to change the uri of the website try it like this:

```
<style>
  #flags {
   position:absolute;
   left:97%;
   top:10px;
   width:300px;
   height:30px;
   background-color:transparent;
  }

  #flags a {
   display: block; /* if you want the link to be a block */
  }
</style>
<div id="flags">
<?php
    $actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $strEng = "eng";
    $strIta = "ita";
    $new_link = str_replace($strEng,$strIta, $actual_link);
?>
  <a id="banner" href="<?php echo $new_link; ?>">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/it-icon-24.png" />
  </a>
  <a href="mydomain.com/bbb/">
    <img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/uk-icon-24.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Also with the above example, you both forget 
Try avoiding inline styles. It works, but if you wanna make a job out of this clients and employers won't like it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
My fault has fallen on the line that specifies the connection to $ new_link variable  
    <a id="banner" href="<?php echo $new_link; ?>">

Comment: No problem :) Try separating your code. It will be more workable when it gets bigger.

Comment: Also, if you can use an <a> instead of a <div> with onclick, do it :) better performance and it works everywhere. Browsers where javascript is disabled won't do the onClicks :) The header.php is the right location in WordPress for this kinda stuff btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference array elements directly inside a string the same way you can with normal variables. You'll have to combine the multiple strings with the `.` operator. See my changes on line 3:

```
<div id="flags" style="position:absolute;left:97%;top:10px; width:300px; height:30px; background-color:transparent">
            <?php
                $actual_link = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                $strEng = "eng";
                $strIta = "ita";
                $new_link = str_replace($strEng,$strIta, $actual_link);
            ?>
            <div id="banner" onclick="window.location.href='$new_link'" style="cursor: pointer">
                <img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/it-icon-24.png" />
            </div>
            <a href="mydomain.com/bbb/"><img src="wp-content/themes/minimable-premium/templates/uk-icon-24.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @oxguy3.
I tried to bring your edit into my code, but the error that i have at onClicked is the "404 Not Found" error: "The requested URL /index.php wan not found on this server"
The URL in the browser in this;  /mydomain.com/$new_link
not the content of the variable ($new_link = str_replace.... )